# mysql select rows of past 3 days for each customer

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I would like to select in MySQL the rows of the past three days for each customer based on their maximum timestamp, yet am not sure how to do this.

Example table:

```
id     | timestamp           | cust_ID
899900 | 2016-04-09 12:00:00 | 500219
899901 | 2016-04-12 16:00:00 | 500219
899902 | 2016-04-14 11:00:00 | 500219
899903 | 2016-04-15 12:00:00 | 500219
909901 | 2016-04-08 16:00:00 | 500230
909902 | 2016-04-14 11:00:00 | 500230
909903 | 2016-04-15 12:00:00 | 500230
939905 | 2016-05-02 19:00:00 | 500240
```

So far I have the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN max(timestamp) AND (max(timestamp) - INTERVAL 3 DAY) 
GROUP BY cust_ID
```

But it gives the error:

> 1111 'invalid use of group function'

Comment: Incidentally, in sql land, 2 is not 'between' 3 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table to an aggregation of itself that finds the max timestamp for each customer:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
JOIN (SELECT cust_ID, MAX(timestamp) max_timestamp    -- each cust_ID's max timestamp
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY cust_ID) m
  ON timestamp BETWEEN max_timestamp - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND max_timestamp
  AND t.cust_ID = m.cust_ID           -- join on the specific cust_ID's max timestamp
```

---

Note also that you must have the smaller expression *first* in a `BETWEEN`, ie

```
WHERE myColumn BETWEEN smaller AND larger
```

If you code it the other way around:

```
WHERE myColumn BETWEEN larger AND smaller  -- don't do this
```

it will still compile and execute, but you won't get any rows returned.

Answer (score 0):

I hope to understand right what you are looking for but could be you need having for aggregate function and not where

```
SELECT cust_id, max(timestamp) 
from table 
GROUP BY cust_ID
having max(timestamp)  BETWEEN  date_sub((max(timestamp) , INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND   max(timestamp)  ;
```

Comment: Wrong semicolon removed .. anyway

Comment: No. It's conceptually wrong. It won't work. You can't be 'HAVING' timestamp. It's not in the SELECT

Comment: I mean 'work' as in the sense of 'won't throw an error'